# Excel AVERAGEIF in Python using alternative table layout

Tags: python, graph, average

I have the following list:

[Attributes are listed in first row and dummy variables check whether a certain candy type fits this critea. The last column shows the "success value" of a certain candy type in each row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mf3n.png)

I would like to create a bar chart that depicts the average winpercent value of each attribute (i.e. chocolate, fruity...). In Excel, I would have created another table as a basis with each attribute at the top and the average value underneath it (using an AVERAGEIF formula). I am, however, uncertain how to accomplish this using Python. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without AVERAGEIF, you can sum the products `attributeIsUsed * winpercent`, and sum the `attributeIsUsed` values, and the average is the ratio of the two.

By `attributeIsUsed`, I mean the `0` or `1` in a cell if that attribute is used in that candy.

### Code in excel

If `C` is the column for `caramel` and `L` the column for `winpercent`, you can add a these formulae in cells C14 to C16, and the average will be in C16:

```
C14 = SUMPRODUCT(C2:C13, L2:L13)
C15 = SUM(C2:C13)
C16 = C14 / C15
```

### Code in python

```py
>>> d = [
... ['chocolate', 'caramel', 'bar', 'winpercent'],
... [1,            1,        0,     66.97],
... [1,            0,        1,     67.60],
... [0,            0,        0,     32.26],
... [1,            0,        1,     50.34],
... [1,            1,        1,     56.91]]
>>> averages = [sum(d[row][col] * d[row][-1] for row in range(1,len(d)))/sum(d[row][col] for row in range(1,len(d)))  for col in range(len(d[0])-1)]
>>> averages
[60.455, 61.94, 58.28333333333333]
```

### Example

The average for caramel is:
`(1 * 66.97 + 1* 56.91) / (1 + 1)`.
You don't need a conditional statement to get that formula, because adding zeroes to a sum is okay!
The average for caramel is:
`(1 * 66.97 + 0 * 67.60 + 0 * 32.26 + 0 * 50.34 + 1* 56.91) / (1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1)`
The numerator is:

`sum(d[row][col] * d[row][-1] for row in range(1,len(d)))`

Here `d[row][col]` is 0 or 1, and `d[row][-1]` is the corresponding winpercent.

The denominator is:

`sum(d[row][col] for row in range(1,len(d)))`

Which is just a sum of zeroes and ones.

If you are using pandas or something similar, you can of course make this code more readable by replacing `for col in range(len(d[0])-1)` with `for col in ['chocolate', 'caramel', 'bar']`, and `[-1]` with `['winpercent']`.

Comment: thanks, I looks good. However, I have the additional problem that my table has stored each value as a str instead of int. Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: Convert to integers with `int()`. In python, `int("37")` evaluates to `37`. If you are using the pandas library, you can convert the whole column with `d['caramel'].astype(int)` or `pandas.to_numeric(d['caramel'])`.